# creating class extending from predefined Superclass

Tags: java, servlets

why java force to extend from HttpServlet while creating any servlet class even if its a abstract class without any abstract methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple because you class need to be sub type of Servlet so that servlet container can use the class according servlet specification.

The servlet container that is the server create instance of you class some how like below

```
Servlet servlet=(Servlet)Class.forName("YourClassName").newInstance();
```

(This is not the exact code but the code will be some how like above)
So if your class is not a sub type of servlet then how the server will use the code.

Answer (score 0):

according to servlet specification it needs to create instance of Servlet so it can't be abstract class

You can choose to go for `@WebServlet` annotation based configuration with servlet 3.0

Answer (score 0):

While `HttpServlet` has no abstract methods, it does have methods that implement non-trivial functionality.  That's why a class is needed. On the flip-side `HttpServlet` needs to be extended in order to implement webapp-specific behaviour, so that is the justification for making it an `abstract` class.

I guess they could have designed the APIs so that there is both an interface and an abstract class, but it shouldn't make any difference in practice.

And besides, as Jigar Joshi points out, you can use annotations instead starting with the Servlet 3.0 spec.

---

When critiquing specs like the Servlet spec, it is necessary to consider the design in the context of what the original Java language looked like; e.g. no annotations, no generic types, and so on).  Also, you need to consider the constraints placed on the spec's evolution by the need to maintain backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

> why java force to extend from HttpServlet while creating any servlet class even if its a abstract class without any abstract methods ?

Well, Java does not force you extend the HttpServlet, it just provides you the facility to extend the HttpServlet and use the basic functionality that is needed for your web app.

HttpServlet provide implementation of some common functionality that is needed for almost every web-app.

If you want to implement these functionality in your own way, you are allowed to do that by by-passing the HttpServlet and extending GenericServlet.

Comment: but if we do so, it cant handle the HttpRequest properly and if so what About ActionForm its too an abstract class..?

Comment: This is exactly why Java provide you HttpServlet, it provides you facility to use Http easilt. It readymade the common utilities for you. But, you are always allowed to work on Http in your own way.